# I Accidentally Deleted a Stock Terminal Theme

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, themes

I accidentally deleted a stock Apple terminal theme that I'd like to get back.  The one I accidentally deleted is called "Pro" (under the Profiles tab in the Terminal settings).  Is there a way to get this back without having to go through an entire installation?

Answer (score 37):

Click the gear icon in the "Profiles" tab and select the option "Restore Default Profiles."

[image]

Comment: It’s always encouraged to ask and answer your own questions, and this is a great Q&A which I’m sure will be helpful for people in a similar situation to find this obscure option!